# SQL count returns error when no GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-error-1140

Why I get error with this query on my live server but not on my wamp localhost?

```
SELECT 
type as type, 
COUNT(*) AS total

FROM page AS p
WHERE p.parent_id = p.page_id
```

the error message is,

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of
>   GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is
>   illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

How can I get around to this?

my localhost return this result which is what I need,

```
type    total
page    16
```

Comment: don't see how it should work on 'localhost; what's the db server you are running locally?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using an aggregate function, such as `COUNT`, you need to include a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause.

```
SELECT 
    type as type, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM page AS p
WHERE p.parent_id = p.page_id
GROUP BY type
```

As far as why this worked locally, but not on your live server; [MySql doesn't require complete listing of non-aggregate columns in the `GROUP BY` clause by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), but your live server probably has the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) option turned on.